# CSS - Can overflow-x be harmful if hidden?

Tags: html, css

I need to give an div a width of 120%. But I don't want horizontal scrollbars, so I set overflow-x hidden for the body. Can the normal website view be harmed by that command?

CSS

```
body{ 
  overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by harmed?

Comment: Just out of curiosity. Why do you need to set a width of 120%?

Comment: What would be the point in having a 120% div, if you cannot scroll to see it?

Comment: Yes, it is known to cause cancer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a `div` with `width: 120%` of the `body` and you give

```
body{ 
  overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

You will not see that `20%` more of the div's content. It will he hidden.

See the working sample: http://jsfiddle.net/carloscalla/tducn765/

It is not "harmful". If you don't want to hide that 20% then you should use `overflow-x: auto;`